# How can I update a div in CakePHP using js->link without a separate view?

Tags: cakephp

There is only one number in the div that I want to update. Is there a way of doing it without 
writing a new view file or should I do it in JS?

I am using CakePHP 1.3 and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the action solved the problem:

```
    $this->autoRender = false;
    return $divContent;
```